# SVN 1.8, when SVN (1.7)-update, the data base got corrupted: 'sqlite: data base image malformed (S11)', and reindex didn't work'

Tags: svn, sqlite, jenkins, tortoisesvn

I use [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) which uses SVN 1.8, after trying to update with an older version of SVN (1.7 via [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29)), the 1.7 SVN-update operation itself failed, then the data base got corrupted. Many files and folders in the .svn folder disappeared. After copying them from another fresh copy (that does not have my local changes) I'm still getting a

```
"sqlite: data base image malformed (S11)",
```

I've tried solutions in *[svn cleanup: sqlite: database disk image is malformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675615/svn-cleanup-sqlite-database-disk-image-is-malformed/15874781#15874781?newreg=34ee57794e5f4875ac64ecb134a38791)*, but they didn't work. I get the following in response to them:

```
C:\my\path>sqlite3 .svn/wc.db "pragma integrity_check"

*** in database main ***

Main freelist: freelist leaf count too big on page 5606

On tree page 5522 cell 116: 2nd reference to page 5606

On tree page 5522 cell 116: Child page depth differs

On page 5522 at right child: invalid page number 5666

row 2995 missing from index I_PRISTINE_MD5

row 2995 missing from index sqlite_autoindex_PRISTINE_1

wrong # of entries in index I_PRISTINE_MD5

wrong # of entries in index sqlite_autoindex_PRISTINE_1

Error: database disk image is malformed

C:\my\path>sqlite3 .svn/wc.db "reindex nodes"

Error: database disk image is malformed

C:\my\path>sqlite3 .svn/wc.db "reindex pristine"

Error: database disk image is malformed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check out a new working copy and delete the old one (after moving your changes over).

Once a WC has been updated to a newer version, you can't use it with an older version. In the past, you just got a message saying that the client was too old for the working copy; with everything being moved into a SQLite database (as of 1.7), there's probably a higher risk of corrupting things when you do this.

Comment: I asked because I didn't want to delete the older corrupted one (as there were some local changes that I didn't commit yet). But seems no other solution till now... I just checked out a new working copy and took my changes manually.