# DB Error: database disk image is malformed- Could not execute the query.Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, sqlite

I am running code from this tutorial [sqlite database iOS app tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/) on XCode 5.1.1  using iOS version 7.1.0. Program is giving sql error on inserting record

```
 DB Error: database disk image is malformed...
 Could not execute the query.
```

On removing the DB file, and creating a new one gives same error.How I can get rid of this db error ?I have visited following links but error remain the same ..
[SQLiteException "database disk image is malformed"](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/) ....[SQLite “database disk image is malformed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623865/sqlite-database-disk-image-is-malformed)

Comment: Watch for multiple threads accessing your DB at the same time (only allow one at a time). And make sure you are cleaning up after yourself using `sqlite3_finalize()` and `sqlite3_close_v2()` e.t.c. These are common ways of corrupting a database.

Comment: The referenced question does not have an answer.

Comment: (Never mind -- I see it's the same author in both cases.)