# What adverse effects would one face if he continued to use SVN after seeing "database disk image is malformed" error

Tags: svn, sqlite

I'm working as a guest dev at a random company. 
I encountered this error "database disk image is malformed".
I reported to the senior dev but he says, "Well, it's fine as long as you can commit your changes. Ignore it".

I would like to know, what would happen if I keep using this SVN repository for more than 2 months(without addressing the issue) which is how long this project will(supposedly) last.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Subversion uses an SQLite database for the checked-out tree, not for the repository itself.

Comment: See [svn cleanup: sqlite: database disk image is malformed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13675615/11654).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite database (in `.svn/wc.db`) contains metainformation about the checked-out files.
If this database does not have the correct information, some Subversion commands might fail, or, even worse, might silently ignore changes, or apply the wrong changes.

<sub>Note: this problem can be easily fixed by checking out the entire tree again into a new directory. Do this, and bill them extra for "advanced Subversion consultancy services".</sub>

Comment: So, in effect, it could result in the corruption of a repository itself, even though the SQLite database itself only contains meta information ?

Comment: I cannot rule it out.