# What is it '���' in db.sqlite3?

Tags: django, python-3.6

I am working on Atom Editor on MacOS,

The first few lines in 'db.sqlite':

```
SQLite format 3@  & :&.���
D�
/O  �X9c��!d��O-�1indexauth_user_groups_user_id_6a12ed8bauth_user_groupsCREATE
```

How to display the `���`?

Comment: why are you opening sqlite3 db in a text editor?

Comment: It looks like database file is corrupted. There are some sqlite GUIs, try to open your database...

Comment: command line `atom .` open it automatically. @AvinashRaj

Comment: the database file is not a text file it contains data that the text editor cant read.

Comment: If I leave it open, things works well.After I closed it, error occurs. In several django projects I created, the repeated operation incur same errors. @AvinashRaj

Comment: so, if it is opened by text editor, error unexpected will occurs? @mohammedqudah

Comment: yep, look for apps that open .db : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't open the `db.sqlite` file in a text editor, try deleting the file and run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

again. It should recreate the `db.sqlite` file.

Comment: It does not work,`django.db.utils.DatabaseError: database disk image is malformed`

Comment: I found someone else who had the same issue...well kinda, you could the solution if it works for u, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675615/svn-cleanup-sqlite-database-disk-image-is-malformed] and if it doesnt work out, you can try creating a new django project in a virtual env and copy your files over to the new project